# gdb: how to easily show/print the stack

Tags: gcc, stack, gdb

Is there a simple way to print the "stack" in gdb? What I mean by this is let's say the base pointer address is:

```
rbp 0x00007fffffffe330
```

And I'm writing values like so:

```
movq $22,       -8(%rbp)
```

And so I could do something like a "stack" command and it would print (at least) something along the lines of:

00
00
00
00
00
00
16

Without having to write something fancy with the `p/x` command that I need to look up to remember how to do it. Is there a straightforward way with gdb to print a readable-ish stack?

---

I suppose the simplest one I've found so far is:

```
>>> x $rbp-8
0x7fffffffe328: 0x00000016
```

Comment: You can add your own commands to gdb.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. thanks for that suggestion. How would I add the command `s` to do `x/8b $rbp-8` ?

Comment: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html Put the definition to `~/.gdbinit`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. thanks, that worked. What syntax does gdb scripting use? Is there a place where I can find out a bit more about how to use that? It seems like a cross between vim and ruby or something.

Comment: It's their own brand of scripting, documented in https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb. You can also script with Python.